# Ascending and descending not working while passing as argument in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am new to mongodb. And using it for a simple operation. I have created one collection named **users** in a database and it will have 2 fields as **fName** & **lname**. Now using python (.py file) I am showing all records. The code is-

```
from pymongo import Connection
from pymongo import ASCENDING, DESCENDING
from sys import argv

#making new connection
connection = Connection()

#mydb  is the database name
db = connection.mydb

# usersis the collection name
collection = db.users 
data = collection.find()

if len(argv) > 2:
   script, fieldname, sortOrder = argv
   data = collection.find().sort(fieldname,sortOrder)
#printing data
for each_data in data:
   print 'First Name: %s, Last Name: %s % (each_data['fname'],each_data['lname'])
```

Now the problem is that if I pass **sortOrder** as argument by command line, it doesn't take it and the result will be in normal way(without any sorting).

So can we pass the 2nd arg of .sort() method as variable or we have to pass **ASCENDING**, **DESCENDING** directly.

Can any one tell the solution.

Comment: Last line of code is missing an end quote after `... Last Name: %s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that sortOrder is a string and ASCENDING and DESCENDING are constants imported from the pymongo module. You'll have to map the sortOrder argument to the constant before you can pass it to the sort method. You can define a dictionary with the valid values for sortOrder:

```
validSortOrders = {'ascending': ASCENDING, 'descending': DESCENDING}
```

Before you pass the sort order to the sort method you get the value from the dictionary:

```
data = collection.find().sort(fieldname, validSortOrders[sortOrder])
```